# How to use URI to edit multiple tables in the same database

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I have a database and within the database i have 3 tables but im using a content provider so how can i distinguish between the tables? i understand the format of the uri and that i would have to use a separate path for each but how do i get the value of the uri with the different paths. do i need to use uri matcher and then that will return the uri i want based on what i put in the parameters? from what i found online it looked like uri matcher was only used for the get type method in the content provider.

Answer (score 0):

> do i need to use uri matcher and then that will return the uri i want
>   based on what i put in the parameters?

Correct. Each of the `ContentProvider`'s methods is called with a `Uri` parameter. You can simply pass that to your `UriMatcher` and then continue in a `switch` statement.

Comment: could you possibly add an example. That is the best way i learn and understand things is by seeing it done.

Comment: Post what you have so far, and I'll extend it to multiple tables. Writing an example from scratch is too time-consuming.

Comment: Im terrible with formatting it properly in a comment. I'll try and simplify/be more clear about my question. If im using my content provider to access 1 of the 3 tables how can i choose which table to access?

do i just call the regular methods but for the uri/authority param do i call the urimatcher method and place the static variable that corresponds to the table path into the matcher params.

Comment: do i just need to create a another uri wherein only the path variable had changed? i was thinking there was a more sophicated way to do it.

Comment: Just update your question -- it'll format well. But yes, you basically add more paths to your UriMatcher instantiation, and then direct the code to the proper table in query/insert/update/delete.